Combine linear16 encoded audio files | PHP
I'm using Google Cloud TTS with PHP, to generate audio files. Large texts are being split to smaller pieces, audio is being generated for each of them, then the media files just combining together, and saved as mp3 file.
It works fine when the audio encoding is MP3, but when the encoding is LINEAR16, the combining does not work. The audio contains only the first piece.
Documentation says, that ->getAudioContent() method returns bace64_encoded audio, but when using with php it is not encoded, just an audio file. You can see it working on this file:
https://storage.googleapis.com/gspeech-audio-storage/gspeech_en-US:2:I:1:0_ef4285edf0514f0b90636718b155c089_9df685f7e3bd36d8ec36cf4faec53c2d.mp3
I'm providing a code which makes main stuff. Any idea how to combine LINEAR16 encoded audio files together using PHP?
...
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioConfig;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SsmlVoiceGender;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SynthesisInput;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\TextToSpeechClient;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\VoiceSelectionParams;

$client = new TextToSpeechClient();
$synthesisInputText = new SynthesisInput();
$audioConfig = new AudioConfig();
// $audioConfig->setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding::MP3); works fine
$audioConfig->setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding::LINEAR16);
$voice = new VoiceSelectionParams();

$voice->setLanguageCode('en-US');
$voice->setName('en-US-Neural2-A');

$media_total = '';
foreach($txt_array as $k => $txt) {

     $synthesisInputText->setText($txt);
     $response = $client->synthesizeSpeech($synthesisInputText, $voice, $audioConfig);
     $media = $response->getAudioContent();

     // $media = base64_encode($media); did not work

     $media_total .= $media;
}

With LINEAR16 encoding, the $media_total contains the audio only from first text piece. With MP3 encoding it works fine.

ffmpeg isn't an option? Or, base64 -d ?

@pierpy Thanks for suggestion. I set up ffmpeg. Any suggestion how to use it in this case? Asked a different question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78958579/ffmpeg-change-audio-encoding-and-combine-audio-files

try to add setSampleRateHertz
$rateHeartz = 16000;
$audioConfig->setSampleRateHertz($rateHeartz);

and combine data PCM to wav file, like this
$wav_header = createWavHeader(strlen($pcm_data), $rateHeartz, 1);
file_put_contents('output.wav', $wav_header . $pcm_data);

function createWavHeader($pcm_data_size, $sample_rate, $channels) {
$block_align = $channels * 2;
$byte_rate = $sample_rate * $block_align;
$header = pack('RIFFVVV4VVVVVVVV',
    0x46464952,
    36 + $pcm_data_size,
    0x45564157,
    0x20746d66,
    16,
    1,
    $channels,
    $sample_rate,
    $byte_rate,
    $block_align, 
    16,
    0x61746164,
    $pcm_data_size 
);
return $header;
}

